# Monit RC and relative paths

Tags: monit

In Monit, is it actually possible to use relative paths? When I use non-absolute paths I get syntax errors.

So when `monit -c etc/monitrc -t` gives an ok syntax status wih the following config

```
set httpd
     port 2812
     with ssl {
        pemchain: /Users/asdf/src/example-django/etc/ssl/certs/monit.chain.pem
        pemkey: /Users/asdf/src/example-django/etc/ssl/certs/monit.key.pem
        SELFSIGNED: ALLOW

     }
     allow myuser:mypassword
```

I get an syntax error if I change it to relative paths: `syntax error 'etc/ssl/certs/monit.chain.pem'`.

Answer (score 0):

In Monit, the absolute path to the file is used. For some more information have a look to the manual, https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html